# What does the timer *below* the pursuit meter mean?

Tags: need-for-speed-world

In [Need for Speed: World](http://world.needforspeed.com/), when you enter pursuit mode by ramming a cop, the escaped/busted meter will appear on the HUD with a little countdown timer at the bottom.  I know that the number on the right is the number of cops chasing you, but what does the timer actually mean?

All I've been able to tell is that when it reaches zero the number on the left increments by one, but nothing else appears to change.

[image: OMG TIMERZ!]

Comment: No love for the freehand circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the timer is the equivalent of NFS:MW's backup timer, except it always counts down and is not (always?) reset after a cooldown period.

Basically, when the timer hits zero some more police cars (how many is not displayed) join on your pursuit, up to a (not displayed) number appropriate for your heat level (not pictured).

Answer (score 0):

It’s the time until you lose him from sight and he loses you (as far as I can remember).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played NFS:W yet, but the readout sounds pretty similar to NFS:MW, in which the number on the left would be the heat level, and the countdown would be when the next round of pursuit vehicles would appear, usually in stronger guise.

Comment: It's not precisely the same. The timer is always counting down, since the start of the pursuit. The "1" in the police shaped thing is _not_ the heat level, I think that's a reinforcement counter. The car number also never decreases.

Comment: ..so other than they they're the same ;). seriously, how does the fun factor compare between the two games? I've got a lot of hours in MW, but I'm thinking I'll just wait for Hot Pursuit.

Comment: The heat level (which influences what *type* and *strategies* the cops use) is entirely separate from the badge-counter-thing next to the timer.  The heat level is on the HUD near the speedometer and is persistent between pursuits (until you're busted).  The badge-counter-thing resets to 1 at the start of every pursuit.